NextJs takes too long to compile in my local environment
I have been working on an app in NextJs but whenever I go to a new route or make a change and reload the page too see it, the app takes too long to compile.
I thought maybe it's because of the modules I am using in my project or unnecessary imports.
So I started a new NextJs project from scratch. And I just ran it using npm run dev and it's still very slow to load the home page.
These are the logs:

✓ Starting...
✓ Ready in 3.4s
○ Compiling / ...
✓ Compiled / in 75.8s (642 modules)
GET / 200 in 77205ms
✓ Compiled in 1184ms (294 modules)
○ Compiling /favicon.ico ...
✓ Compiled /favicon.ico in 7.7s (345 modules)
GET /favicon.ico 200 in 7970ms

This is really slowing down my development speed.
Are these normal compilation times?

The compilation times can vary extremely, but in your case that seems to be far above the average. Does it only take that long on the first render when using npm run dev?
If so, let me know which modules you are using. Ie complex UI/UX modules like framer-motion or Three.js can cause long compilation times especially when you are developing on a slow machine without GPU.
I recently had a next.js project which a friend of mine wasn't even able to run in dev mode, it crashed as soons as he tried to compile any page...he was using a very bad cpu, no gpu at all and less than 2GB ram

As I said, even start a boilerplate nextjs project takes too long to start using npm run dev without installing any extra modules.

On what OS are developing? Which IDE?
